# Error en Javascript: "Uncaught TypeError: isTripDay is not a function"

Tags: javascript

```js
var tripDay = prompt('Porfavor ingrese el numero de dia en el que desea viajar');

while (!isTripDay() || !confirmDay()){

function isTripDay(){
  if (tripDay >= 1){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

function confirmDay(){

  return confirm('Realmente desea comprar un pasaje para el dia '+tripDay+' ?');
  }

}
```

Comment: @santiagoDantuoni la variable tripDay no es una funcion

Comment: Cual seria tu objetivo con el código que tienes?

Comment: no acepta ninguna respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Te indica este error porque estás definiendo las funciones dentro del bucle y no las está detectando como que estén declaradas. Tendrías que sacarlas fuera para que te las detectara.

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```js
var tripDay = prompt('Porfavor ingrese el numero de dia en el que desea viajar');

while (!isTripDay() || !confirmDay()){
   alert("hemos entrado");

}

function isTripDay(){
  if (tripDay >= 1){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}


function confirmDay(){

  return confirm('Realmente desea comprar un pasaje para el dia '+tripDay+' ?');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tenia razon Rene, pero en realidad lo pude solucionar de esta forma. Ahora funciona como deseaba

```js
do {
 
var tripDay = prompt('Porfavor ingrese el numero de dia en el que desea viajar');


function confirmDay(){

  return confirm('Realmente desea comprar un pasaje para el dia '+tripDay+' ?');
  } 

function isTripDay(){
  if (tripDay >= 1 && tripDay <= 25){
    alert('Perfecto su viaje esta programado para el dia '+tripDay);
    return true;
  }else{
    alert('Lo sentimos, el dia seleccionado no tiene viajes programados');
    return false;
  }
}


}while (!confirmDay() || !isTripDay())
```

Answer (score -2):

Así como el error lo dice:

> TypeError: isTripDay is not a function

es una variable y por lo tanto `()` está de sobra

```js
var tripDay = prompt('Porfavor ingrese el numero de dia en el que desea viajar');

function confirmDay(){

  return confirm('Realmente desea comprar un pasaje para el dia '+tripDay+' ?');
  }

while (!isTripDay || !confirmDay()){

function isTripDay(){
  if (tripDay >= 1){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}


}
```

Comment: Es una función, solo que al momento de llamarla, todavia no esta definida.

Comment: si aún no está definida aún no es una función. De no ser así no habría ningún error.

Comment: Si te fijas detenidamente la variable `isTripDay` no existe, es decir que su valor es `undefined`. Por lo tanto `!isTripDay` es `true`. ¿Cual seria  el objetivo de hacer eso? Y aún mas importante si no se supone que es una función,  ¿por que entonces un par de lineas mas abajo se define `function isTripDay(){`?